# How to edit multiple text lines in a .ini file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch scripting but i would like to use it to automatically edit following   values in a .ini file

Example.ini (Please note that its a configuration file with lot of other entries before, after and in between these two entries.)

```
[Log]
Enabled = 0   

[Support]
Line1 = ÿ
Lines = 1
SenderAddress = Report@example.com
```

The updated values should look like this : ( [Log] Enabled = 1 & [Support] MailSenderAddress should become blank)

```
[Log]
Enabled = 1

[Support]
Line1 = ÿ
Lines = 1
SenderAddress =
```

Evenutally, I would like to include the code to update these entries in a master .bat script.

Could you guys please help me with this?

Comment: May be more than one line with `Enabled` or `SenderAddress` in the file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes that's right, There are more than one line with Enabled & SenderAddress in the file. That's why i have mentioned [Log] and [Support] blocks which are unique.Also, is it possible to update the same file instead of creating a new file?? Because this particular ini file is a part of a software and i do not want to create another file and play around with the file/folder structure of the software.

Comment: I suggest you to use `python` if possible. `ConfigParser` in `python` supports reading and writing `.ini` style files naturally and robustly.

Comment: Thanks Landys, i have got absolutely no clue of python, i would prefer a batch script because then i could include this code in our master script which basically installs the software by calling setup.exe. Could i do something like this with python and wouldn't it need some sort of service/app/software to be installed in windows? coz batch script can run on windows without the need of any sort of external app or software so we can offer this bat files to any of our clients without having to worry about whether it would run fine on their machine or not coz we know that it would work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "logsection="
SET "supportsection="
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (q25635303.txt) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
   SET repro=Y
   IF "%%c"=="" (
    SET "logsection="
    SET "supportsection="
    IF /i "%%b"=="[Log]" SET logsection=y
    IF /i "%%b"=="[Support]" SET supportsection=y
   ) ELSE (
    IF DEFINED logsection IF "%%b"=="Enabled" (SET "repro="&ECHO(Enabled = 1)
    IF DEFINED supportsection IF "%%b"=="SenderAddress" (SET "repro="&ECHO(SenderAddress =)
   )
   IF DEFINED repro ECHO(%%a
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt

FC q25635303.txt newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25635303.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Begorrah, but it's difficult to work with a small target section in isolation, it is, it is.

The above should work - well, does work on your provided data, but without a fuller listing of the .ini file, it's not possible to be very positive.

The `fc` at the end is simply to compare the before and after version for verification. The sticking point that I have is whether the item which has a value assigned to it may include a space. Adjustments would be required if that is so...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes that's right, There are more than one line with Enabled & SenderAddress in the file. That's why i have mentioned [Log] and [Support] blocks which are unique.Also, is it possible to update the same file instead of creating a new file?? Because this particular ini file is a part of a software and i do not want to create another file and play around with the file/folder structure of the software

Comment: The problem with edit-in-place is that when the output file is opened by redirection, it's cleared, so there's no input data available from that file. However, changing `q25365303.txt` in the `for... %%a...` line above to `'type newfile.txt'` (the single-quotes are **required**) buffers `newfile.txt` before it's opened for output, apparently curing the problem (at least, it did for me). Obviously, `copying` q25635303.txt to newfile.txt first allows you to test the changes. When testing is complete, remove the `copy` and substitute your chosen filename for `newfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i am using find and replace instead. Much easier